# Resize a warehouse from x-small to medium in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Resize a warehouse from x-small to medium in snowflake is for what purpose.Kindly clarify.
To accommodate more queries or to accommodate more user or to optimized workload or to optimized complex workload.

Answer (score 2):

There are detailed explanation on following link.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-tasks.html#resizing-a-warehouse

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the performance of a query/complez workload, you would change the size of the warehouse.
If you want to increase performance of number of users (how many concurrent users snowflake can handle) then you would increase number of nodes or clusters.

Eg.

alter warehouse my_wh set warehouse_size=XLARGE ; --Improves performance of query/workload

alter warehouse my_wh set MAX_CLUSTER_COUNT = 16
MIN_CLUSTER_COUNT = 2 -- Improves concurrent user and the performance of their queries

Comment: Thanks! i have one more question.snowflake is used for OLAP and OLTP /OLAP and concurrent data/OLAP and onpremise data.